# How can use front and back camera simultaneously

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

im try coding in Android Studio front and back camera simultaneously but my coding use only one side
what i need to change or add coding?

I hope someone help me

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class CameraTest003 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView,mSurfaceView02;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceViewHolder,mSurfaceViewHolder02;
    private Handler mHandler,mHandler02;
    private ImageReader mImageReader,mImageReader02;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice,mCameraDevice02;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder,mPreviewBuilder02;
    private CameraCaptureSession mSession,mSession02;
    private int mDeviceRotation;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private Sensor mMagnetometer;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private DeviceOrientation deviceOrientation;
    int mDSI_height, mDSI_width;

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270, 270);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.camratest001);


        ImageButton button = findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });

        mSurfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        mSurfaceView02 = findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewvideo);


        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        deviceOrientation = new DeviceOrientation();

        initSurfaceView();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(deviceOrientation.getEventListener(), mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(deviceOrientation.getEventListener(), mMagnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(deviceOrientation.getEventListener());
    }


    public void initSurfaceView() {

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        mDSI_height = 300;
        mDSI_width = 300;


        mSurfaceViewHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

        mSurfaceViewHolder02 = mSurfaceView02.getHolder();

        mSurfaceViewHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                initCameraAndPreview();

            }
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                if (mCameraDevice != null) {
                    mCameraDevice.close();
                    mCameraDevice = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }
        });

        mSurfaceViewHolder02.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                initCameraAndPreview02();

            }
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                if (mCameraDevice02 != null) {
                    mCameraDevice02.close();
                    mCameraDevice02 = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }
        });




    }







    @androidx.annotation.RequiresApi(api = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void initCameraAndPreview() {


        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("CAMERA2");
        handlerThread.start();
        mHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());


        try {
            String mCameraId = "" + CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT; 
            CameraManager mCameraManager = (CameraManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);


            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);


            Size largestPreviewSize = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)[0];
            Log.i("LargestSize", largestPreviewSize.getWidth() + " " + largestPreviewSize.getHeight());


            //카메라 프리뷰
            setAspectRatioTextureView(largestPreviewSize.getHeight(),largestPreviewSize.getWidth());
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largestPreviewSize.getWidth(), largestPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG,/*maxImages*/7);
            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mainHandler);


            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, deviceStateCallback, mHandler);



        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "카메라를 열지 못했습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    @androidx.annotation.RequiresApi(api = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void initCameraAndPreview02() {


        HandlerThread handlerThread02 = new HandlerThread("CAMERA2");
        handlerThread02.start();
        mHandler = new Handler(handlerThread02.getLooper());
        Handler mainHandler02 = new Handler(getMainLooper());


        try {
            String mCameraId02 = "" + CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT; 

            CameraManager mCameraManager02 = (CameraManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics02 = mCameraManager02.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId02);


            StreamConfigurationMap map02 = characteristics02.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);


            Size largestPreviewSize02 = map02.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)[0];

            //카메라 프리뷰
            setAspectRatioTextureView02(largestPreviewSize02.getHeight(),largestPreviewSize02.getWidth());


            mImageReader02 = ImageReader.newInstance(largestPreviewSize02.getWidth(), largestPreviewSize02.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG,/*maxImages*/7);
            mImageReader02.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener02, mainHandler02);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            mCameraManager02.openCamera(mCameraId02, deviceStateCallback02, mHandler02);



        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "카메라를 열지 못했습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

            Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            new CameraTest003.SaveImageTask().execute(bitmap);
        }
    };

    private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener02 = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader02) {

            Image image02 = reader02.acquireNextImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer02 = image02.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes02 = new byte[buffer02.remaining()];
            buffer02.get(bytes02);
            final Bitmap bitmap02 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes02, 0, bytes02.length);
            new CameraTest003.SaveImageTask().execute(bitmap02);
        }
    };


    private CameraDevice.StateCallback deviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            try {
                takePreview();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            if (mCameraDevice != null) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            Toast.makeText(CameraTest003.this, "카메라를 열지 못했습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };


    private CameraDevice.StateCallback deviceStateCallback02 = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera02) {
            mCameraDevice02 = camera02;
            try {
                takePreview02();

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }




        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            if (mCameraDevice02 != null) {

                mCameraDevice02.close();
                mCameraDevice02 = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {

            Toast.makeText(CameraTest003.this, "카메라를 열지 못했습니다.2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };


    public void takePreview() throws CameraAccessException {

        mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(mSurfaceViewHolder.getSurface());
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(mSurfaceViewHolder.getSurface(), mImageReader.getSurface()), mSessionPreviewStateCallback, mHandler);

    }


    public void takePreview02() throws CameraAccessException {

        mPreviewBuilder02 = mCameraDevice02.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewBuilder02.addTarget(mSurfaceViewHolder02.getSurface());
        mCameraDevice02.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(mSurfaceViewHolder02.getSurface(), mImageReader02.getSurface()), mSessionPreviewStateCallback02, mHandler02);

    }


    private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback mSessionPreviewStateCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            mSession = session;
            try {

                mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
                mSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mHandler);

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Toast.makeText(CameraTest003.this, "카메라 구성 실패", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };


    private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback mSessionPreviewStateCallback02 = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {

            mSession02= session;
            try {

                mPreviewBuilder02.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                mPreviewBuilder02.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
                mSession02.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder02.build(), null, mHandler02);


            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Toast.makeText(CameraTest003.this, "카메라 구성 실패2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    };


    private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mSessionCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            mSession = session;
            unlockFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
            mSession = session;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureFailure failure) {
            super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
        }
    };



    public void takePicture() {

        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);//用来设置拍照请求的request
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader02.getSurface());
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);


            //deviceRotation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            mDeviceRotation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation.getOrientation());
            Log.d("@@@", mDeviceRotation+"");

            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, mDeviceRotation);
            CaptureRequest mCaptureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();
            mSession.capture(mCaptureRequest, mSessionCaptureCallback, mHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int degrees) throws Exception {
        if(bitmap == null) return null;
        if (degrees == 0) return bitmap;

        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setRotate(degrees, (float) bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (float) bitmap.getHeight() / 2);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
    }



    /**
     * Unlock the focus. This method should be called when still image capture sequence is
     * finished.
     */
    private void unlockFocus() {
        try {
            // Reset the auto-focus trigger
            mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                    CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
            mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
            mSession.capture(mPreviewBuilder.build(), mSessionCaptureCallback,
                    mHandler);
            // After this, the camera will go back to the normal state of preview.
            mSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), mSessionCaptureCallback,
                    mHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static final String insertImage(ContentResolver cr,
                                           Bitmap source,
                                           String title,
                                           String description) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, title);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());

        Uri url = null;
        String stringUrl = null;    /* value to be returned */

        try {
            url = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            if (source != null) {
                OutputStream imageOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
                try {
                    source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, imageOut);
                } finally {
                    imageOut.close();
                }

            } else {
                cr.delete(url, null, null);
                url = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (url != null) {
                cr.delete(url, null, null);
                url = null;
            }
        }

        if (url != null) {
            stringUrl = url.toString();
        }

        return stringUrl;
    }


    private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            Toast.makeText(CameraTest003.this, "사진을 저장하였습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... data) {

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = getRotatedBitmap(data[0], mDeviceRotation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, ""+System.currentTimeMillis(), "");

            return null;
        }

    }


    // 출처 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43516672
    //카메라 프리뷰 함수
    private void setAspectRatioTextureView(int ResolutionWidth , int ResolutionHeight )
    {
        if(ResolutionWidth > ResolutionHeight){
            int newWidth = mDSI_width;
            int newHeight = ((mDSI_width * ResolutionWidth)/ResolutionHeight);
            updateTextureViewSize(newWidth,newHeight);

        }else {
            int newWidth = mDSI_width;
            int newHeight = ((mDSI_width * ResolutionHeight)/ResolutionWidth);
            updateTextureViewSize(newWidth,newHeight);
        }

    }

    private void setAspectRatioTextureView02(int ResolutionWidth , int ResolutionHeight )
    {
        if(ResolutionWidth > ResolutionHeight){
            int newWidth = mDSI_width;
            int newHeight = ((mDSI_width * ResolutionWidth)/ResolutionHeight);
            updateTextureViewSize(newWidth,newHeight);

        }else {
            int newWidth = mDSI_width;
            int newHeight = ((mDSI_width * ResolutionHeight)/ResolutionWidth);
            updateTextureViewSize(newWidth,newHeight);
        }

    }

    private void updateTextureViewSize(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        Log.d("@@@", "TextureView Width : " + viewWidth + " TextureView Height : " + viewHeight);

        mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight));

    }


    public class DeviceOrientation {

    private final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90; // 6
    private final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_REVERSE = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180; // 3
    private final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL; // 1
    private final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_REVERSE = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270; // 8

    int smoothness = 1;
    private float averagePitch = 0;
    private float averageRoll = 0;
    private int orientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    private float[] pitches;
    private float[] rolls;

    public DeviceOrientation() {
        pitches = new float[smoothness];
        rolls = new float[smoothness];
    }

    public SensorEventListener getEventListener() {
        return sensorEventListener;
    }

    public int getOrientation() {
        return orientation;
    }



    SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        float[] mGravity;
        float[] mGeomagnetic;

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
                mGravity = event.values;
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
                mGeomagnetic = event.values;
            if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
                float R[] = new float[9];
                float I[] = new float[9];
                boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
                if (success) {
                    float orientationData[] = new float[3];
                    SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientationData);
                    averagePitch = addValue(orientationData[1], pitches);
                    averageRoll = addValue(orientationData[2], rolls);
                    orientation = calculateOrientation();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    private float addValue(float value, float[] values) {
        value = (float) Math.round((Math.toDegrees(value)));
        float average = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < smoothness; i++) {
            values[i - 1] = values[i];
            average += values[i];
        }
        values[smoothness - 1] = value;
        average = (average + value) / smoothness;
        return average;
    }

    private int calculateOrientation() {
        // finding local orientation dip
        if (((orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_REVERSE)
                && (averageRoll > -30 && averageRoll < 30))) {
            if (averagePitch > 0)
                return ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_REVERSE;
            else
                return ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        } else {
            // divides between all orientations
            if (Math.abs(averagePitch) >= 30) {
                if (averagePitch > 0)
                    return ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_REVERSE;
                else
                    return ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                if (averageRoll > 0) {
                    return ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_REVERSE;
                } else {
                    return ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i dont know  how i can do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using both front and back cameras simultaneously android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419940/using-both-front-and-back-cameras-simultaneously-android)

Comment: Another link to a more recent question. Basically not all phones can do this. [How to configure front and back both cameras simultaneously in Android camera2 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509423/how-to-configure-front-and-back-both-cameras-simultaneously-in-android-camera2-a)